# Erlang preference page error in in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, erlang, erlide

I am new to erlang. I installed erlide plugi and When I try to open the Erlang Preferences (Window -> Preferences -> Erlang) I get the following error, "An error has occured when creating this preference page.". I have attached the logs for the error.
This is a new workspace I created. It used to work with eclipse Luna. I tried to use it in Eclipse Mars and I got this error. So, I tried to check with the previous versions of eclipse and I am still getting the same error. Not sure what went wrong.

I also tried uninstalling my erlang (erl5.9.1)
Could someone please help me what I am missing here?

```
     eclipse.buildId=4.5.2.M20160212-1500
java.version=1.7.0_79
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -data file:/C:/Codebase/ -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.eclipse.equinox.registry
Error
Mon Sep 12 09:25:07 CDT 2016
Unable to create the selected preference page.

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.erlide.ui (961).
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:573)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorDefinition$1.run(LightweightDecoratorDefinition.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorDefinition.internalGetDecorator(LightweightDecoratorDefinition.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorDefinition.decorate(LightweightDecoratorDefinition.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager$LightweightRunnable.run(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager.decorate(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:367)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager.getDecorations(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$1.ensureResultCached(DecorationScheduler.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$1.run(DecorationScheduler.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error starting module.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/erlide/backend/api/IBackendListener
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2585)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2885)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:706)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.erlide.backend (944).
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.erlide.backend.internal.BackendActivator.start() of bundle org.erlide.backend.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:792)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.erlide.runtime.runtimeinfo.RuntimeFinder.findRuntime(RuntimeFinder.java:118)
    at org.erlide.runtime.runtimeinfo.RuntimeFinder.guessRuntimeLocations(RuntimeFinder.java:40)
    at org.erlide.runtime.runtimeinfo.RuntimeInfoCatalog.initializeRuntimesList(RuntimeInfoCatalog.java:187)
    at org.erlide.runtime.runtimeinfo.RuntimeInfoCatalog.setRuntimes(RuntimeInfoCatalog.java:46)
    at org.erlide.runtime.api.RuntimeCore.getRuntimeInfoCatalog(RuntimeCore.java:21)
    at org.erlide.backend.BackendCore.getRuntimeInfoCatalog(BackendCore.java:28)
    at org.erlide.backend.internal.BackendActivator.start(BackendActivator.java:21)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    ... 55 more
```

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the latest version 0.33.1 But, had the same issue. Someone mentioned somewhere about the 'Check Updates' option for a similar issue. So, I tried check updates for Erlide plugin which brought it down the plugin version. I tried this couple of times and each time it brought down the version. Finally I was able to settle with verion 0.31.0  Seems like plugin compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

What version of erlide is it? Can you try with the latest one, 0.33.1? I believe this problem is the same as the one fixed there (#290@github).

Also, please use https://github.com/erlang/erlide_eclipse/issues for reports

best regards,
Vlad